# How do I get ALL of my product items to show up on the homepage of magento 1.3.2?

Tags: magento, shopping-cart, product, cart, catalog

I installed Magento v1.3.2.3 and added most of my product inventory. However, I can only get 5 items to display on the homepage. I need all my products to show up there. How?

This is currently the code I am using.

```
{{block type="catalog/product_new" name="home.catalog.product.new" alias="product_homepage" template="catalog/product/new.phtml"}}
```

I found this on the magento community forum.

Comment: I think you would be better off posting on their community forums - it's unlikely that someone who happens to be familiar with this software is around on a Saturday.

Answer (score 0):

[This link](http://www.chilipepperdesign.com/2009/03/23/magento-how-to-list-all-the-products-in-a-single-category-in-a-sidebar-block) explains how to display products in a particular category on the homepage. You just have to remove the category filter from the code given there to get all the products.

```
$products   = $product->setStoreId($storeId)  
                      ->getCollection()  
    ->addAttributeToFilter(‘visibility’, $visibility)  
    ->addCategoryFilter($category)  
    ->addAttributeToSelect(array(‘name’), ‘inner’) //you need to select “name” or you won’t be able to call getName() on the product 
    ->setOrder(‘name’, ‘asc’)
;
```

change this to

```
$products   = $product->setStoreId($storeId)  
                      ->getCollection()  
    ->addAttributeToFilter(‘visibility’, $visibility)   
    ->addAttributeToSelect(array(‘name’), ‘inner’)
    ->setOrder(‘name’, ‘asc’)
;
```

That should set you on the right track. Good luck!